# How to fix inconsistent mysql results?

Tags: mysql, sql-order-by, union, union-all, sql-limit

My `MySQL` query

```
(SELECT * FROM names WHERE Rate = 75 ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 1) 
UNION 
(SELECT * FROM names WHERE Rate = 75 ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 1) 
UNION 
(SELECT * FROM names  WHERE Rate = 35 ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 1);
```

it should give me something like this

```
+----+-----+------+
| id | Rate| num  |
+----+-----+------+
| id |  75 |  987 |
| id |  75 |  987 |
| id |  35 |  987 |
+- --+-----+------+
```

but sometimes it only gives me 2 rows, something like this

```
+----+-----+------+
| id | Rate| num  |
+----+-----+------+
| id |  75 |  987 |
| id |  35 |  987 |
+- --+-----+------+
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`UNION` removes duplicate rows.

The first 2 queries may return the same row and in this case one of them will only be in the results.

If you don't mind duplicate rows in the results then change to `UNION ALL`:

```
(SELECT * FROM names WHERE Rate = 75 ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 1) 
UNION ALL 
(SELECT * FROM names WHERE Rate = 75 ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 1) 
UNION ALL
(SELECT * FROM names WHERE Rate = 35 ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 1);
```

If you want unique rows then unify the first 2 queries to only 1 with `LIMIT 2` so that they return 2 rows:

```
(SELECT * FROM names WHERE Rate = 75 ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 2) 
UNION ALL 
(SELECT * FROM names WHERE Rate = 35 ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 1);
```

I use here `UNION ALL` because it performs better than `UNION`.

Answer (score 4):

Note the difference between `UNION` and `UNION ALL`

- UNION will remove duplicate rows
- UNION ALL keeps all rows

Answer (score 0):

To get 3 *different* rows from the table, do simply:

```
SELECT * FROM names WHERE Rate = 35 ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 3;
```

Comment: The requirement is 2 rows with Rate = 75 and 1 row with Rate = 35.